# Access selected record's grid value and passing to a new window using javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, gridview

Here in my form, i need to open a new window when i click the edit button in my grid view.also the corresponding ID value must be passed to the new window.I wrote the code for opening in a new window but it s not working.I searched and couldnt find how to send the selected record's ID value to the new window.Help me how to do this.

```
     <asp:GridView ID="gridUserDetails" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
                                BorderColor="#336666" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" 
                                GridLines="Horizontal" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="true"  
                                onselectedindexchanged="gridUserDetails_SelectedIndexChanged" onsorting="SortingGridData">
                                <Columns>                                     
                           <asp:BoundField DataField="ID"  HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" />
                           <asp:BoundField DataField="Name"  HeaderText="Employee Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                           <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Employee Address" SortExpression="Address" />
                           <asp:BoundField DataField="Email"  HeaderText="Employee Mail"  SortExpression="Email"/>
                           <asp:BoundField DataField="Department"  HeaderText="Department"  SortExpression="Department"/>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" Text="Edit" 
                    onClientClick="windowopen()"/>


                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                </Columns>
                                <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <PagerStyle BackColor="#336666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#339966" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
                                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#487575" />
                                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
                                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#275353" />

                            </asp:GridView>
```

This is the code for my Grid.And below is my javascript

```
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function windowopen() {
           mywindow = window.open('ISSRegistrationForm.aspx', 'Employee Details', 'height=500, width=1100, status=no, resizable=no, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no,location=no, menubar=no'
            }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an anchor(a tag) inside a new TemplateField's ItemTemplate:

```
<asp:TemplateField><ItemTemplate><a href="onclick="javascript:windowopen('<%#Eval("ID") %>')">Click Here</a></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
```

and your JavaScript function should look like this:

```
    function windowopen(id) {
mywindow = window.open('ISSRegistrationForm.aspx?id='+id, 'Employee Details', 'height=500, width=1100, status=no, resizable=no, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no,location=no, menubar=no')
            }
```

Comment: @yasir.:u have suggested to use anchor tag.I have to use it in a buttom field.help me how to use it in a button.!?

Comment: @AjithKumar if you want it to look like a button then you can use an input tag of type "button" instead of anchor, like: `<input id="myButton" type="button" onClick="javascript:windowopen('<%#Eval("ID") %>')" />`